# FBSDKGraphRequest : result - Value of optional type 'Any?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

Original Syntax :

[image: []

Error is

> Value of optional type 'Any?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'? on `result` variable

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameter).start { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        if let email = result["email"] as? String {
            print(email)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `result` is supposed to be a dictionary, you have to optional downcast and unwrap `Any?` to the expected type:

```
if let item = result as? [String:Any],
   let email = item["email"] as? String {
        print(email)
}
```

Comment: Then the structure of the result doesn’t match. Post `result` if you can

Comment: The `result` might not contains an "email", depends on whether the loggedin user wants to show his/her email, it is related to the privacy policy...

Answer (score 0):

The `completionHandler` closure for the `start` method contains three parameters, implemented as follows (Objective C):

```
typedef void (^FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                         id result,
                                         NSError *error);
```

<sub>[Source code reference.](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.h)</sub>

Thus the `id` data type would be [transformed](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39) to be `Any` (Optional) type, meaning that for the Swift closure, the parameters would be:

```
(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, Any?, Error?)
```

As mentioned in the documentation:

> - Parameter result:          The result of the request.  This is a translation of  JSON data to `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` objects. 
>     This  is nil if there was an error.

So you would need to cast it as a Swift Dictionary as `[String : AnyObject]` and then get your "email" String from it:

```
if let unwrappedResult = result as? [String : Any], let email = unwrappedResult["email"] as? String {
    print(email)
}
```

Comment: I can't get email from Facebook user

Comment: @Meas are you sure that the user *enables* to show his/her email? it depends on the user privacy setup. If the `error` is `nil`, then you should get the desired data -such as the email-.